# var/locks is always empty

Tags: indexing, reindex, indexer

I do see the var/locks folder in my Magento installation. But it is always empty - even while the indexer is running.

I assume it will cause an issue if the indexer gets triggered more than once, is this correct?

But I can't track down why it always stays empty.

1. var/locks is set to 777 [drwxrwxrwx]
2. var/locks will be owned by the same user of var/logs (and this works)
3. all indexes finish successfully
4. Nothing related in log files
5. Magento ver. 1.9.2.0

I appreciate any hint and further information. Thank you.

**Edit**:
If I'm gonna overwrite the indexer module with one from ver. 1.8 it works like expected - the var/locks folder will be used. So it looks like Magento changed the way of using var/locks? Does anyone know more about it?

Thanks!

Comment: try: TRUNCATE index_event;
TRUNCATE index_process_event;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the locking mechanism has indeed changed and seems now to be in db per default.

In 1.8 it looked like this:
https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php#L454

In 1.9 the locking mechanism was changed and handled by an own Model:
https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php#L458

It still seems possible to set the use_file_lock data to true, but since its not done here, i assume that db is the default now.

https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php#L128

Looking at the Lock Model there is also the db lock as default.